# CSS error in Simple CSS plugin

Tags: plugins

I am noticing this error in our Simple CSS plugin.

**Warning: The type attribute for the style element is not needed and should be omitted.**

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you!

Sandy

Comment: You should not repost the same question, use the edit link under the list of tags to update it instead

Comment: I'm sorry about that! I thought it was easier to do separate posts because they were different plugins and there were different warning / error messages for each. In any case, I received your other message about third-party plugins being off topic. Thank you for your assistance!